# How to make tick width larger so that all the tick content is seen

Tags: vega-lite

Here, I want the text to fully show.

[image]

I had looked at docs on [customizing size](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html), and [tick size](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/tick.html#example-customizing-ticks-size-and-thickness), but still cannot find what I need. When I adjust the overall width, i seem to only make the bars wider. Thanks

[editor link here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgYATgGtsUdui1qNkZEvjcAJoyXV9oCBEgBPB5ABmjZGKv7IAI6syLB4PCqqUHguhMj+3Fo2SuhialDoAB6MsO5heGJxOAAMAL4l6k5QGe7o1NRawniFUJasSnhpkNGx-kHo7czoYVSdmdm5zAX6peUazpZiCQ5zTp7evv5I3IzwcRWVUTHNkAlJKSYHUAgpzcCQDVRasM0AjLOXkAXU5n44d3lTHCQAASPkIHlYYiUIRyJRWcIg7ygViGmD+K0gFBSwRyOAA2isII5LlAgiEwsp-MDuAB3MDcDxNJRgKzcMAubisMCsZ5gAA8jAAfKEhjs+aQhWAKNlWClGAAvUXKWAAfguJMgWx2xwAgmIaegXDlCWAkZViR8yaFwlTafTGeYWWyOVyech+ULbE0tOh4MNkOLJdLYLKJIqKUpVeqPlrdv4AHLIR6QE1mpwWg6BHER210hlMp3sznc3kC4V4UXwQOCqUyuXh8JR-YxxDbONAvUGo0py5pokm5xWnNA6l5h3M1lF12lz3tZA+v2MKjV2sh+tKyNq5uZ2PHADK3FQyDCR+Nve3-ZJpOzNpHdvzjsnLpL7rLIrCVYlNeDoYVG6bA4tK22r+AA8uOPYHH2YAZpUWbkreUCjvaBZPsWboeoKXrzr6-orj+64RgBV6asB7ZQAeR4niEkGVNBsGrEOiEgve46Fs+GFvhWH74XWYb-lugGkW2ur6oaZ5QReMFCUxlJ3mOqHOuhM5YXOC54V+q6-g2yqCSRu7+JRx6MKetFOPRMk3nJSGsYpU4vph75ippBH8URekagZQJGdREl0VJDGDlZKjyShj5KdOr6zt6uFLgGLl8X+7nRjuZH7oexmmamAWWQh1ksQp4X2ZxQpOZ+QaJTpm4pXBXlQOBTJmYiOUkbJIU2YVE4RQ5ZbYepcW8WubmNh5LYif4ABKRg+G4qYrAAuhocIlEAA)